# jQuery fadeOut() function on input type button

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, fadeout

I've got an input type button on my page, with the CSS of:

```
input[type="button"] {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 2px solid darkgreen;
    /*border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;*/
}
```

When you click the button it changes the color via JQuery and then it should fade out.  Everything works except it fading out.  Instead of fading out it just disappears.  Here is my jQuery code...

```
 $('#process').click(function() {
        $(this).css({"background-color":"black", "color":"white"});

        $(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'parser.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#checkup-form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert('error; ' + eval(error));
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

it will wait for the time, but won't fade...it just disappears like I used the hide function and immediately goes into my ajax call.  I've tried commenting out the .css() segment but that doesn't seem to change anything with it.  Again, it'll pause for the 800 or ever how long I put in there, but will not fade out, it'll just disappear.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the JS snippet. I have deleted the last line and now it fades out.

```js
 $('#process').click(function() {
        $(this).css({"background-color":"black", "color":"white"});

        $(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'parser.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'post',
                data: $('#checkup-form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $(this).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
                    });
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert('error; ' + eval(error));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
}

input[type="button"]:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: 2px solid darkgreen;
    /*border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="process">
```

I fixed it by limiting the transition to just the properties needed (please add the vendor prefixes):

```
transition-property: color, background-color;
```

Comment: I apologize, I must have copied that last }); by accident, that last }); actually went with the $(document).ready().  But, if that's all you deleted from it and it's fading properly...the question is, why is't it fading on my end.  Hmm...this will take some investigation.  I'm using chrome currently, I'll try it in other browsers.

Comment: yeah, it is rather odd.  It starts fading, fades part of the way out then just disappears and jumps into the ajax call like it completed it's animation.  If you want to see the actual page it's on, maybe that will help figure it out and you'll see something I missed, it's located at http://ag.kirindesigns.com

Comment: I seem to have some what fixed it by using the fadeTo(800, 0, function(){...}) but it's still triggering the end animation function before the fade is actually complete.  Kind of strange, but the effect now looks kind of neat, I might like it that way.  It starts to fade the button, then a little over half way it starts to fade the whole page out...I can live with that.  I'd still like to know what's going on, however.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the problem please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you!  It's working perfect now!  Much appreciated!